# Argparse parse set of arguments condtionally

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to parse one of two sets of arguments based on the first argument that is passed.
Something like the code mentioned below. It currently would read all arguments as a part of --argument1. Is there a way I can achieve this?

```
parser.add_argument('--argument1',help='argument that would decide which set of arguments to parse')
conditional_argument = parser.parse_args().argument1
if conditional_argument == 'condition1':
      #add and parse arguments based on condition1
      parser.add_argument('--argument1_condition1')
      parser.add_argument('--argument2_condition1')
      arg1_conditon1 = parser.parse_args().argument1_condition1
      arg2_conditon1 = parser.parse_args().argument2_condition1
elif conditional_argument == 'condition1':
      #add and parse arguments based on condition2
      parser.add_argument('--argument1_condition2')
      parser.add_argument('--argument2_condition2')
      arg1_conditon2 = parser.parse_args().argument1_condition2
      arg2_conditon2 = parser.parse_args().argument2_condition2
```

Comment: Sounds like you want [subcommands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)

Comment: Instead of `script --argument1 condition1 ...` or `script --argument1 condition2 ...`, you'll just write `script condition1 ...` or `script condition2 ...`.

Comment: Use parse_kownn_args()` for the first parsing.  And `args = paser.parse_args()` for the second(s).  Don't need to repeat the `parse_args` for each attribute.